# Show #id - hide #id when hover another #id

Tags: jquery

How can make in jQuery something like this:

`<div id="principal-id"></div>` // this is principal id what is displayed

`<div id="hover-id"></div>` // when I hover #hover-id I want the #principal-id to disappear and change with 
`<div id="this-id"></div>`.
But is a way when I'm with cursor on #this-id to stop change, and when the cursor is moved outside return to normal?

I hope you understand...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a little cleaner:

```
<div id="hover-id" style="border:1px solid black">hover over me</div>

<div id="principal-id">normal</div>
<div id="this-id" style="display:none">replacement</div>

var hover = function(){
    $('#principal-id').toggle();
    $('#this-id').toggle();
};

$('#hover-id').mouseenter(hover).mouseleave(hover);
```

as in: http://jsfiddle.net/HQQAV/

Comment: cleaner could be debatable.  Nice demo though.  It definitely solves the problem and proves that there is more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: @jmort253, agreed, in fact i upvoted Box9's solution which is a nicer version of mine

Comment: Box9's is by far the best.  I forgot you could comma separate CSS selectors.  I'll have to remember that one.

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your problem.  When I mouseover (hover) over hover-id, the principal-id will be hidden, and when I move my mouse cursor away from the hover-id, the principal-id will once again be displayed:

```
   // define the mouseover event for hover-id
   $('#hover-id').mouseover(function() {
         $('#principal-id').css('display','none');
   });

   // define the mouseout event for hover-id       
   $('#hover-id').mouseout(function() {
         $('#principal-id').css('display','block');
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's `hover` and `toggle` magic:

```
$('#hover-id').hover(function () {
    $('#principal-id, #this-id').toggle();
});
```

But just make sure `#this-id` is initially hidden, through any of the below options:

1. CSS: `#this-id {display: none;}`
2. Inline-CSS: `<div id="this-id" style="display: none">`
3. JavaScript: `$('#this-id').hide();`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hover-id").mouseover(function() {
         $('#principal-id').hide();
   });

   $('#hover-id').mouseout(function() {
         $('#principal-id').show();
   }); 
});

// you didn't close the ready function correctly.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```
$("#hover-id").hover(function(){
              $("principal-id").hide();
            }, 
            function(){
              $("principal-id").show();
            });
```