# Rollover text/img-based link to show an image

Tags: jquery, image, animation

I found a flash piece on a website I'd like to emulate using JQuery:
http://www.jbcoxwell.com/construction_services.html

In searching this site, I found one post useful as the basis for starting my script:
[Show #id - hide #id when hover another #id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704823/show-id-hide-id-when-hover-another-id)

I got as far as getting the hover to work and show the photo area. I'm more of a novice enthusiast and sometimes have problems with syntax and such, but when it really broke down is when I tried to target the id of the text link on rollover and match it to the image. I am not sure how to match the text with the right image. I know that using an ID twice is a no-no, so how do I group two items in likeness but also separate them when it comes to functionality?

Here is my html code:

```
<body><div id="container">
<div class="text" id="txt1">Service 1</div>
<div class="text" id="txt2">Service 2</div>
<div class="img" style="display: none" id="img1">Photo 1</div>
<div class="img" style="display: none" id="img2">Photo 2</div></div></body>
```

My CSS:

```
 #img1 {
 background-image: url(image/img1.jpg);
 background-color: red;}
 #img2 {
 background-image: url(image/img2.jpg);
 background-color: blue;}    
.text {
 width: 150px;
 height: 15px;
 background-color: #7a7a7a;
 float: left;
 clear: left;
 margin-bottom: 25px;}
.img {
 width: 300px;
 height: 100px;
 float: right;}
```

And my .js file:

```
$(function() {
    // define the mouseover event for text
$('.text'+this.id).mouseover(function() {
        $('.img').css('display', 'block');
    });

    // define the mouseout event for text       
$('.text'+this.id).mouseout(function() {
        $('.img').css('display', 'none');
    });

});
```

I've spent time looking through this and other sites for snippets here and there but I seem to keep going in circles. I'd love to understand where I'm going wrong with this. Thank you for your time!

*Edit: Here is the most functional version I was able to make this:
http://jsfiddle.net/aburgin/EKb4E

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/hAsX3/2/

You ended up using the ids #1 and #2 for multiple elements - don't do that.  I stored the id of the corresponding element in the text element's data attribute.

Comment: Thank you as well! I tried your answer but I received the same result I described in my response to Jen. And thanks for the reminder about IDs... I knew that but for some reason I missed it.

Comment: Well, there's the d'oh moment. I was working on a site from scratch and forgot that I had to include the code! I KNEW I was missing something. I'll search right now. Also, I was curious about your use of "data-image" - is this another way to assign an identifier to an element without making a style? It seems like this is easier to target in the script. Eventually I want to add a background-image to the text (or an image swap) but I thought I would tackle that in CSS. Would using this help me to define different images for each service name if I wanted to? Just leaning to one bg image for now.

Comment: data-* is an html5 custom attribute.  jQuery's data() function lets it work on old browsers too.  You can store anything you want in there and retrieve it later.  In this case, I'm just storing another element's id (prepended with a # for the selector).

Comment: Hooray! That is what I was hoping for. I really appreciate the explanation as well; I like knowing the data function makes the html5 attribute compatible. I'll work over the two versions tomorrow night and post back about which one worked best for me. Again, many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="container">
<div class="text" id="image1">Service Name 1</div>
<div class="text" id="image2">Service Name 2</div>
<div class="img image1" style="display: none" id="1">Photo 1</div>
<div class="img image2" style="display: none" id="2">Photo 2</div>
</div>


$(function() {
    // define the mouseover event for text
    $('.text').mouseover(function() {
        $('.' + $(this).attr("id")).css('display', 'block');
    });

 $('.text').mouseout(function() {
    $('.' + $(this).attr("id")).css('display', 'none');
});

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/EKb4E/56/

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I have a different issue now; when I tested the page in my broswer, I'm getting a "$ is not defined" error in firebug. It references the function opener. All I have in my .js file is what I originally posted, then updated when I copied from your answer. The .js file is linked in my html file. Would you have any ideas?

Comment: The jquery core file should be above you linked .js. Check and make sure. This is pretty simple. It should run.

Comment: Thanks Jen! It took a lot longer than it should have but I got it. Silly mistakes as a result of getting reacquainted with scripting. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dennis & Jen I was able to use their answers to come up with a nearly complete script to mimic the example in my original post. I used the structure of Jen's script but included the nifty trick shared by Dennis. The data text names are used in my up/over image names so I could piece them together while manipulating them in the script. The only part missing is having the hovered item stay visible until another item is hovered. But this is something I will try to figure out on my own. Here is what I was able to put together:

HTML:

```
<div id="serv_list">
  <div id="text_list">
    <div class="text" id="img1" data-text="serv1" style="background-image: url(services/serv1_up.png);"></div>
    <div class="text" id="img2" data-text="serv2" style="background-image: url(services/serv2_up.png);"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="img_list">
    <div class="img img1" style="display: none" id="1"></div>
    <div class="img img2" style="display: none" id="2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#serv_list {
margin-top: 20px;}
.img1 {
background-image: url(services/serv1.jpg);}
.img2 { 
background-image: url(services/serv2.jpg);}
#text_list {
float: left;
width: 200px;}
.text {
width: 200px;
height: 18px;
float: left;
clear: left;
margin-bottom: 25px;}
#img_list {
float: right;
width: 450px;}
.img {
width: 450px;
height: 300px;
float: right;
clear: both;}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
$('.text').mouseover(function() {
var bg = $(this).data("text");
$('.' + $(this).attr("id")).css('display', 'block');
$(this).css('cursor','pointer');
$(this).css('background-image', 'url(services/' + bg + '_ovr.png');
});
$('.text').mouseout(function() {
$('.' + $(this).attr("id")).css('display', 'none');
$(this).css('background-image', 'url(services/' + $(this).data("text") + '_up.png');
});
});
```